# Mysql order by parent and child

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I want to display a result of query sorted by parent and then the child.
Here's my code

```
SELECT * FROM 
mst_category AS parent 
LEFT JOIN mst_category AS child 
ON child.category_parent = parent.category_id
GROUP BY parent.category_id
ORDER BY parent.category_group, COALESCE(parent.category_parent, parent.category_id), parent.category_parent != 0, child.category_id
```

The result of the query :

[image: query result]

As you can see some of the children are not sorted by parent id. My question is how to sort it ?

Comment: how many levels deep are you looking to go? use of parent.category_parent!=0 implies only one, but it's clear from the data there is more than one. normally you would use recursion for that, but in mysql you are probably looking for something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984074/mysql-tree-ordered-by-parent-and-child

Comment: @Mic but in my table, there is no Order column, only id and parent id ..

Comment: Um, what's category_group? That said, the data shown goes to three levels and if that's the lowest depth the point is moot. It's not quite clear from the question exactly what you're trying to do which is why I asked how many levels you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your order by clause to just what you want the sort order to be:

```
SELECT 
    parent.category_id as `parent_id`,
    parent.category_group as `parent_group`,
    child.category_id as `child_id`
    child.category_group as `child_group`
FROM mst_category AS parent 
LEFT JOIN mst_category AS child 
    ON child.category_parent = parent.category_id
GROUP BY parent.category_id
ORDER BY parent.category_group, child.category_group
```

For 3 levels:

```
SELECT 
    parent.category_id as `parent_id`,
    parent.category_group as `parent_group`,
    child.category_id as `child_id`
    child.category_group as `child_group`,
    child2.category_id as `child2_id`
    child2.category_group as `child2_group`
FROM mst_category AS parent 
LEFT JOIN mst_category AS child 
    ON child.category_parent = parent.category_id
LEFT JOIN mst_category AS child2
    ON child2.category_parent = child.category_id
WHERE parent.category_id = 0
GROUP BY parent.category_id, child.category_id, child2_category_id
ORDER BY parent.category_group, child.category_group, child2.category_group
```

Comment: I found it this way http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed673/7/0, but it's not showing the third level menu, only second level as the example.

Comment: Of course it's only displaying one child. To display the next level, you would need to add another join.

Comment: It's closed, I added `GROUP BY parent.category_id, child.category_id, child2.category_id` so if there is more than one child it will loop and show the child, but the parent gets doubled. [Screenshoot](http://imgur.com/a/NYT6x)

Comment: You would need to add parent.category_id = 0 in a where clause to ensure that each row's parent is a top level item. I'll update the answer.

Comment: If that works for you, please accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I already added `parent.category_id=0`, but I still had a problem like I said above.