# MySQL recursion query with child value

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I have a table **pages**

[image: pages table]

I want to select all tree by Id

for example when I give parent value **2** or child value **36** it is return me

[image: result query]

please help me

Comment: Did you check the below posts? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984074/mysql-tree-ordered-by-parent-and-child

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+mysql+and+tree

Comment: I think, that you can't get the resulting tree as a sql resultset. How would you expect the result to be displayed? You can't display a tree in a table. So I would recomment you to implement the logic in your code. Like, getting the parent (or child) of your current entry, then query the parent (or child) of the resulting entry, and so on...